# Magento 2 Ajax call not working

Tags: magento2, ajax, mini-cart

I am trying to update whole **minicart** content but my **ajax call** is not working

```
$.ajax({
    url: "my_controller_url",
    type: "POST",
    success: function (result) {
        $(".minicart").html(result);
    }
});
```

Comment: If you are getting 404 error than it may be due to routes.xml

Comment: I am not sure this is 404 or something else. How can I verify?

Comment: check networking console log of browser for get error code.

Comment: ok. let me check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all run ajax URL directly to check if your URL is working.

If it is working, then you need to add your `ajax` in `require` function and use `jQuery` instead of `$` sign, like this:

```
require([
    'jquery'
], function($){
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: "my_controller_url",
        type: "POST",
        data: "",
        success: function (res) {
            jQuery(".minicart").html(result);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank @Shoaib Munir, let me check this one